# Symfony2: Session, CSRF Protection, etc. only for one firewall / site area

Tags: symfony

I'm looking for a way to enable session and CSRF Protection for only a **part** of my application.

The reason is that I'm writing a REST API with a small admin backend. For the admin backend I need all this functionality, but for the main part, I don't and I want to avoid the overhead.

I can set `stateless: true` on the main part, but I was wondering if there is a better way of disabling those selectively enable/disable all the things I need only in selected parts of my app.

I'm using FOSRestBundle for the REST part.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CSRF protection per role. The user who connects to the API should have (in this example) a `ROLE_API` role:

```
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
```